# Getting WCF RIA Service Timeout

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services, wcf-configuration

I am running heavy WCF RIA service operation and getting such error on client-side Silverlight app:

```
    Uncaught Error: Unhandled Error occurred in Silverlight Application:
Submit operation failed. Для запроса HTTP к 

"https://localhost/MyProject/ClientBin/myservice.svc/binary" has exceeded the allotted timeout. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.


Stack Trace:
   в System.Windows.Ria.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
   в System.Windows.Ria.SubmitOperation.Complete(Exception error)
   в System.Windows.Ria.DomainContext.CompleteSubmitChanges(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   в System.Windows.Ria.DomainContext.<>c__DisplayClassd.<SubmitChanges>b__5(Object )
```

I am getting such timeout in 1 minute of execution.

My context looks like that:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class ConfigService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<MyEntityFrameworkEntities>
```

Here is code screenshot:

[image: My context class]

Comment: you should add endpoint in your code :factory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

Comment: http://lemeaow.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/howto-increase-timeout-globally-in-ria-services/

Comment: I have Factory with 2 methods: ReleaseDomainService and CreateDomainService. Nothing else. Let me try to cast to ChannelFactory

Comment: I am using RIA Beta I have no DomainContext class at all

Comment: ihave no idea about RIA Beta Sorry Bro....

Comment: if you like my research the upvot me ....your wellcome bro....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ach of the settings discussed in this topic are made on the binding itself, either in code or configuration. The following code shows how to programmatically set timeouts on a WCF binding in the context of a self-hosted service.

```
public static void Main()
            {
                Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/MyServer/MyService");

                try
                {
                    ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService));

                    WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
                    binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                    binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
                    binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

                    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint("ICalculator", binding, baseAddress);
                    serviceHost.Open();

                    // The service can now be accessed.
                    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
                catch (CommunicationException ex)
                {
                    // Handle exception ...
                }
            }
```

The following example shows how to configure timeouts on a binding in a configuration file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

you shoud edi For RIA Service

**Either one line after domain context creation:**

```
((WebDomainClient<LibraryDomainContext.ILibraryDomainServiceContract>)this.DomainClient).ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
```

or a partial class

```
public partial class LibraryDomainContext
{
   partial void OnCreated()
   {
      if(DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(App.Current.RootVisual))
         ((WebDomainClient<LibraryDomainContext.ILibraryDomainServiceContract>)this.DomainClient).ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually the error is connected more to RIA Services, not to WCF in general meaning

Comment: I extended my custom class with LinqToEntitiesDomainService<MyEntityFrameworkEntities>

Comment: Probably this would be an answer if I use RIA Release version

Comment: public partial class LibraryDomainContext
{
   partial void OnCreated()
   {
      if(DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(App.Current.RootVisual))
         ((WebDomainClient<LibraryDomainContext.ILibraryDomainServiceContract>)this.DomainClient).ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
   }
} hey man! this gonna work! BUT ChannelFactory is non-public....

Answer (score 0):

When calling from a client you want to increase the **sendTimeout** attribute.

**closeTimeout** = The time interval for the connection to close

**openTimeout** = The time interval for the connection to open

**receiveTimeout** = The time interval a service allows the connection to be inactive

**sendTimeout** = The time interval the client waits for a response

Comment: Right, I saw it, but it doesn't works. Maybe because I am using RIA Services. Do you know, how to tweak it?

Comment: not sure about RIA... try this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/11/03/how-to-change-the-request-timeout-for-wcf-ria-services.aspx